# Chaining observable in service and subscribe in the end at component with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, observable

Platform - Angualar 2 + TypeScript + angularFire2

Inside my user.service.ts, I have the following code to make a first request to a end point in firebase to find out some path information. Then I want use that path information to perform a second query to find details about the user.

```
  getUserInformation(uid: string) {
    this.angularFire.database.object('/pathForUid/' + uid).subscribe(results => {
      let path = results.path;
      return this.angularFire.database.object('/uses/' + path)
    });
  }
```

I think there is a problem with this code because if I include the return type FirebaseObjectObservable (which is what database.object returns,) I get the following error

[image: screen shot]

What I want to achieve is to be able to call this function in my login.component.ts file as demonstrate below . Currently, when I do that, I get a red underline on my subscribe saying

> property "subscribe" does not exist on type "void

```
onLogin() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.userService.loginWithEmailPassword(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password)
      .then(
      data => {
        this.alertService.success('Login successful', true);
        console.log('Login successful', data)

        // This is what I want to achieve
        this.userService.getUserInformation(data.uid).subscribe(result => {
          console.log(result)
        });

        //this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        this.loading = false;
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.error(error.message);
        console.log('Error occured', error)
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

-----Update-----
I am not sure what is happening with the double return as I came from swift. As soon as I add it in, I get an error as shown in the image. If I dont add the return type FirebaseObjectObservable (after I put in the return at the start as you mentioned, I get an error at subscribe saying "property subscribe does not exist on type Subscription. So to me it seems like the function is actually returning Subscription instead of firebaseObjectObservable where I can subscribe. How can I change it so that I can subscribe to it?

[image: update]

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text instead of screen shot. An additional screenshot is great, but screenshots are not searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return something (as the error says ;-) )

```
getUserInformation(uid: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
  return this.angularFire ...
```

Comment: Hi Gunter, Thanks for the response. I have tried a few things. Please see my updated question

Comment: If you want to return an `Observable` you must not call `subscribe()` on it, because `subscribe()` returns a `Subscription`. If you replace `subscribe` with `map` you should get what you want.

Comment: What a magical function map is. Works great thanks. Will look into it a bit more

Answer (score 1):

You should return the method call inside the `getUserInformation`, otherwise it returns `void`. Which obviously does not have a `subscribe` method.. being that it's void:

```
getUserInformation(uid: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
    return this.angularFire.database.object('/pathForUid/' + uid).subscribe(results => {
         let path = results.path;
         return this.angularFire.database.object('/uses/' + path)
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey mate. Thanks for the reply. Please see my updated question. I am not sure what is happening with the double return as I came from swift. If I dont add the return type FirebaseObjectObservable<any> (after I put in the return at the start as you mentioned, I get an error at subscribe saying "property subscribe does not exist on type Subscription. So to me it seems like the function is return Subscription instead of firebaseObjectObservable<any>